# Linux - Too many closed connections

Tags: linux, sockets, netty

I'm coding an application opening on a single linux machine 1800 connections/minute using Netty (async nio). A connection lives for a few seconds and then it is closed or it is timeouted after 20 secs if no answer is received. More, the read/write timeout is 30 secs and the request header contains `connection=close`. 
After a while (2-3 hours) I get a lot of exceptions in the logs because Netty is unable to create new connections due to a lack of resources. 
I increased the max number of open files in limits.conf as:

```
root            hard    nofile           200000
root            soft    nofile           200000
```

Here is the output of `netstat -nat | awk '{print $6}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n`:

```
   1 established)
   1 FIN_WAIT2
   1 Foreign
   2 TIME_WAIT
   6 LISTEN
  739 SYN_SENT
 6439 LAST_ACK
 6705 CLOSE_WAIT
12484 ESTABLISHED
```

This is the output of the `ss -s` command:

```
Total: 194738 (kernel 194975)
TCP:   201128 (estab 13052, closed 174321, orphaned 6477, synrecv 0, timewait 3/0), ports 0

Transport Total     IP        IPv6
*         194975    -         -
RAW       0         0         0
UDP       17        12        5
TCP       26807     8         26799
INET      26824     20        26804
FRAG      0         0         0
```

Also `ls -l /proc/2448/fd | wc -l` gives about 199K.

That said, the questions are about the closed connections reported in the `ss -s` command output:

1)what are they exactly?

2)why do they keep dangling without being destroyed?

3)Is there any setting (timeout or whatever) which can help to keep them under a reasonable limit?

Comment: What is the *exact* error message and stack trace, and what does `netstat` show?

Comment: Is this some kind of network-namespaced environment (docker host / docker container / ...)? The numbers just don't add up.

Comment: @Roman No it is a real machine with no virtualizations. They might be a little different because they have been got at different times while the app was runnong  (just executed the commands in a short sequence but not at the same instant) and because fd includes all the open file descriptors not just sockets (my guess).

Comment: Try running `sudo lsof -n -p pid` (replace `pid` with actual value) and inspecting the output for most frequent entries (and share the results with us).

Answer (score 4):

> 1)what are they exactly?

They are sockets that were either never connected or were disconnected and weren't [`close`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/close.2.html)d.

In Linux, an outgoing TCP socket goes through the following stages (roughly):

1. You [create](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html) the socket (unconnected), and kernel allocates a file descriptor for it.
2. You [`connect()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html) it to the remote side, establishing a network connection.
3. You do data transfer (read/write).
4. When you are done with reading/writing, you [`shutdown()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shutdown.2.html) the socket for both reading and writing, closing the network connection.
5. You [`close()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/close.2.html) the socket, and kernel frees the file descriptor.

So those 174K connections `ss` reports as closed are sockets that were either not gone past stage 1 (maybe `connect()` failed or even never called) or gone through stage 4, but not 5. Effectively, they are sockets with underlying open file descriptors, but without any network binding (so `netstat` / `ss` listing doesn't show them).

> 2)why do they keep dangling without being destroyed?

Because nobody called [`close()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/close.2.html) on them. I would call it a "file descriptor leak" or a "socket descriptor leak".

> 3)Is there any setting (timeout or whatever) which can help to keep them under a reasonable limit?

From the Linux point of view, no. You have to explicitly call [`close()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/close.2.html) on them (or terminate the process that owns them so the kernel knows they aren't used anymore).

From the Netty/Java point of view, maybe, I don't know.

Essentially, it's a bug in your code, or in Netty code (less likely), or in JRE code (much less likely). You are not releasing the resources when you should. If you show the code, maybe somebody can spot the error.

Answer (score 2):

As Roman correctly pointed out, closed connections do exist and are sockets which have never been closed properly.
In my case I had some clues about what was going wrong which I report below:

1)`ss -s` showed stranges values, in particular a lot of **closed** connections

2)`ls -l /proc/pid/fd | wc -l` showed a lot of open descriptors

3)Numbers in `netstat -nat | awk '{print $6}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n` did not match with the previous ones

4)`sudo lsof -n -p pid` (Roman suggestion) showed a lot of entries with **can't identify protocol**.

Looking around on the web I found an interesting post (https://idea.popcount.org/2012-12-09-lsof-cant-identify-protocol/) which explains what really point 4 might mean and why netstat numbers do not match (see also here https://serverfault.com/questions/153983/sockets-found-by-lsof-but-not-by-netstat) .

I was quite surprised, since I used netty 4.1.x (with Spring) with a common pattern where every connection was supposed to be properly closed, so I spent a few days before understanding what was really wrong.

The subtle problem was in the netty IO thread, where the message body was copied and put in a blocking queue (as part of my code). When the queue was full, that slowed down things, introducing some latency and causing a connection time out not detected by my end and, consequently, the leak of FDs.

My solution was to introduce a sort of pooled queue preventing netty requests when the queue is full.

Answer (score 0):

You still haven't provided the exact error message I asked for, but as far as I can see the question should be about the six and a half thousand connections in CLOSE_WAIT state, not 'those closed connections'.

You're not closing sockets that the peer has disconnected.

> That said, the questions are about those closed connections.

What closed connections? Your `netstat` display doesn't show any closed connections. And there is no evidence that your resource exhaustion problem has anything to do with closed connections.

> 1)what are they exactly?

They aren't.

> 2)why do they keep dangling without being destroyed?

They don't.

> 3)Is there any setting (timeout or whatever) which can help to keep them under a reasonable limit?

As they don't exist, the question is meaningless.

Comment: As written, currently the hard and soft limits are set on 200K open files/sockets, so 6K CLOSE_WAIT connections should not be a problem. More,  the application generate 1.8K connections every minute and, considering timeouts and certain latency in handle them, I would say 6K close_wait connecton after a few hours is not the real problem. Anyway, you did not answer any of my 3 questions and collecting the whole stacktrace reqire some time (I need to add some logs, restart the application and wait till the problem appears).

Comment: You didn't answer mine either. There shouldn't be *any* CLOSE_WAIT connections, or only a few. The 'closed connection' count is the number of connections TCP has closed. It isn't a problem. Closed connections cannot cause resource exhaustion, as they are not resources, as they no longer exist. It's the ones that *do* exist that are the problem, and specifically the 6.5K CLOSE_WAIT connections you have leaked. But until you provide the exact error message I keep asking for, it is impossible to help you further.

Comment: Well, it is still not clear to me. `ss -s` does just report the aggregate number of the content of /proc/app-id/fd. Running `ls -l /proc/2448/fd | wc -l` gives 199670 and `ss -s` shows `TCP:   199289 (estab 5079, closed 192835, orphaned 330, synrecv 0, timewait 1/0), ports 0`, so I guess closed connections do still exists.

Comment: It will never be clear until you provide the exact error message and stack trace that I have now asked for four times. What is clear is that you are leaking connections. You are not reacting to end of stream by closing the socket,

Comment: Once again, my question is not about why I have a lack of connections, but what those closed connections are. And the stacktrace which you requires will not help you to say that.

Comment: Then you are asking a question about the inner workings of `ss` which doesn't appear to have any bearing whatsoever on your secret exception. And your title remains an assumption which is not justified by any evidence whatsoever. You can argue all you want but the task in front of you is to fix your connection leak. You will have to do it sooner or later, and whether you like what you're being told here or not.